# Christian convert into Islam will he get to paradise?

Tags: quran, jannah, christianity

I want to know if in  any verse     in the Quran Allah say that the converted will enter paradise first for they have believe in two prophet which is Jesus pbuh and Mohammad pbuh.?

Comment: It seems like you haven't done any research on the subject at all. Who even said that the Christians are going to hell or not paradise?

Comment: @Asrah can you define who are Christians?  Do you mean those who identify themselves as Christians?  I ask because, removing the title and the people focusing on what Jesus pbuh taught (how to live, worship, and treat each other) isn't too different between the big 3 monotheism religions.  While there are some important differences when it comes to trinitarian Christians, ultimately who gets judged and goes where is not up to us - it is up to Allah.  We (Muslims, Christians, and Jews) are just trying to live by what is explained to us in hopes to be judged accordingly as well as help others.

Comment: I always say, "Call me not of the name of your religion.  I worship the one God.  If I am wrong in parts of my beliefs, God will understand that I am just trying to understand him.  After all, he gave me this brain, he knows what tools I have to work with." ;)  I read the holy books - not of just one religion, but of many (truth is truth is truth).  Today it's hard to find people who read the holy book which is of the religion they profess let alone other books.

Comment: You need to understand who the authors are.  Make sure that you're reading what the prophets say and not what the author has said.  Otherwise, the author is your prophet.

Answer (score 2):

Please try, at least, a google search. It is a pleasure to answer any serious questions you may have, but I respectfully ask you to respect the users of this website by making an effort.

Short answer: Yes. And it is not even said that Christians won't go to heaven. The Quran talks about "those who believe and do good deeds" not "those who are Muslims and do good deeds".

Yes, Muslims believe in **all** the prophets, including Jesus who has a very important place (One of which being the Messiah) but is not the son of God.